# GLUT and multithreading

Tags: multithreading, glut

if I have a mainthread that sets up a GLUT window and then create a working thread to do calculations and during the calculations upon some events in the working thread i want to update my GLUT window. How can I do that?
Apparently I can't call the glut functions directly from the working thread.

I thoght of setting some 'updateflag' that gets checked in the glut Idle Loop and if it's set then to redraw the GLUT window, but aparently it doesn't work to call glut functions from the idle loop either (or at least shouldn't be done).

So - what's the proper way to do that?

thanks!

Comment: The only reasonable answer is "don't (even try to) do that." glut was basically designed as enough of a framework to allow the examples in the book to work, but not much more than that. You really need something more capable.

Answer (score 0):

That's a common problem with most GUI frameworks (most are normally not threadsafe).

The normal solution is posting invocations to the main event loop. I am not sure what thread library you use (some will probably have the concept of delegates etc), but in your case a simple event queue would probably do it.

And yes, you can redraw the window from the idle function. At least I've always done it...

Answer (score 0):

well I've implemented multi-thread on GLUT for calculations what I do it's ad a bool flag that tells the glut once an event has happened on the other thread, then I have a stack with data collected on the other thread and just reuse the stack on the main GLUT thread, on that way I manage to keep glut working but not stopping the rendering.

I use Async <- for multithread functions